# BLE Notification

Tags: ios, iphone, core-bluetooth

I need to write four commands to BLE one by one after Notification.(ie:For every command the BLE will notify, then I have to read the data. Depends on that data I need to send the next write command.)

The issue is,

I am writing the First Command to BLE. It notifies me. Then am sending the second command. The writing has been done.(didWriteValueForCharacteristic called). But the notification is not working.
Thanks.

Comment: you're using some timer in the process of the notification creation? i had the same problem but fixed it with register the notification using the main thread and also some timer was run in background thread

Comment: @DekelMaman  Am not using any timer and did set Notify to YES on Main thread.  When I run the first command in a loop it notifies me. But when I run the second command it is not notifying.

Comment: you can post your code?

Comment: @DekelMaman  The issue is resolved. Thanks. In firmware side (BLE Peripheral) there is a timer which will do disconnect if the commands are not being received in that time.

Comment: happy to hear that, So it was some timer?

Comment: OK i'll answer please marked it as solved?

Comment: hi can you please mark my Answer as Solved?

Answer (score 4):

you're using some timer in the process of the notification creation?
 i had the same problem but fixed it with register the notification using the main thread and also some timer was run in background thread
Put attention on disconnect timers if you have any